# Linux swap space usage not freed

Tags: linux, memory, swap, top

i received alerts on one of my systems (RHEL6) saying that it had a high swap space usage.

after looking at the VM, i can indeed see that the swap is fully utilized, while we have more than enough physical memory available, e.g:

```
[root@xxxxxxxxxx ~]# free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           11G       5.3G       6.3G       2.6M       196M       560M
-/+ buffers/cache:       4.6G       7.0G
Swap:         4.0G       4.0G        21M
```

so my question is :

does it mean that the system ran out of physical memory at some point, and "had to" use these 4Gbs of additional SWAP. the memory was freed afterwards, but the swap remains high.

and if that is the case, is there a way to "empty" that swap?

when running a **top** on the machine, filtering by swap usage, i can see see some processes using that SWAP (the java at the top in particular with *2.7g)*

```
top - 14:57:06 up 72 days, 19:54,  4 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.02, 0.00
Tasks: 201 total,   1 running, 200 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.2%us,  0.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  12197860k total,  5598708k used,  6599152k free,   201704k buffers
Swap:  4193276k total,  4170820k used,    22456k free,   573636k cached

    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  SWAP COMMAND
   9180 pcmc03    20   0 7428m 980m 9208 S  0.3  8.2 797:35.54 2.7g java
   9474 pcmc03    20   0 3409m 999m 9.8m S  0.0  8.4 492:09.57 513m pmrepagent
   9455 pcmc03    20   0 2702m 1.5g 3712 S  0.0 13.0  29:42.06 297m pmrepagent
   9383 pcmc03    20   0 4362m 229m 1568 S  0.3  1.9 159:45.77 213m java
   9494 pcmc03    20   0 2705m 108m  10m S  0.3  0.9 183:49.58  61m pmserver
   7371 root      20   0  231m  69m 2104 S  0.0  0.6 360:27.50  60m prismd.pl
   1730 root      20   0  117m  44m  920 S  0.0  0.4  33:45.09  46m rootmon
```

does it mean that this java process had to use 2.7g of swap at some point and kept the reservation?
and if so , i guess this system might need additonal memory to avoid similar situations in the future?

a **vmstat** does not show any si/so.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it looks like you were low on memory. No don't try to free it from swap. If you do it will go into RAM. However it may be worth seeing what processes are wasting memory, and asking do they need to exist?

Comment: thanks, they do.. but i rarely have memory issues on that box, so i'm guessing the process had some kind of issue or huge needs at some point, as the machine has 6Gbs free now. it would mean that it required 10gbs+ of memory a couple of hours ago, i suppose. Why would this swap space go into the ram if freed. as i suppose it's not in use anymore ? why is it not rebalanced automlatically into the ram ? (which is quicker)

Comment: If freed then it is gone. I meant freed from swap is bad. It is best to stay there. If it is still there then it is because it has not been used since the free RAM has appeared. If a process reads or writes it then it will be swapped back to RAM. The stuff in swap will be stuff that the OS guessed would not be used. The fact that it is still there, indicates that it got the guess correct.

Comment: this makes perfect sense, thanks for the comment